# How can I use TypeScript that was produced in WebStorm right away from html?

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, phpstorm, webstorm

I have tried all answers but I have stacked with errors like

> main.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

when I use compile to es5 as target

and

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

when I use compile to es6 as target

main.ts

```
import {MyLib} from './mylib';
let myLib = new MyLib("Anonymous", "Someone");
console.warn(myLib);
```

mylib.ts

```
export class MyLib {
    constructor(public a: String, public b: String) {

    }


    toString() {
        return "library tostring: " + this.a + " " + this.b;
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

index.html

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>
            ts-demo !!
        </title>

        <script type="module" src="./require.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="./system.min.js"></script>

        <script src="./tsdemo/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to set the `<script>` type to `module` to make ES6 modules work, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="module" src="./tsdemo/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

2. also, the `.js` extension is required in import to make it work in browser. Typescript compiler doesn't have options to auto-add it (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577), but you can add the extension in your `main.ts` file, like:

```
    import {MyLib} from './mylib.js';
    let myLib = new MyLib("Anonymous", "Someone");

    console.warn(myLib);
```

tsc does the right thing and resolves types from the `.ts` file, preserving the extension in generated javascript

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know by they way why I can't use es5 and getting this "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" I do have require.js in my index.html

Comment: when targeting `es5`, default module format in generated javascript is `CommonJS` that can't be used in browser. You can override default option by specifying `"module": "amd"` or `"module": "umd"` (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). `amd` is supposed to be used with require.js

Comment: After I added module:"amd" I get "main.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined". It may sound silly but I can't find amd.js file to download.

Comment: works fine for me using `amd`. Please make sure to load your files in amd way: `<script data-main="main" src="require.js">`